# Windows 8: Creating a custom contract

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I want to implement a custom contract for my apps to programmatically share data with each other without involving a user.

I do not see any documentation on implementing a custom app contract for Windows 8 store apps.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe you can create your own contracts outside of the ones Microsoft provides.